# using new in function prototype's property

Tags: javascript

I've seen a Javascript project where a prototype property is defined like this:

```
myFunc.prototype.a = new myObject()
```

I'm wondering what happens when I call `new myFunc()` to the a property:

Does it return the result of `new myObject()` or everytime I call `myFunc.a` it calls new `myObject()`?

And on different `myFunc` instances the `a` property is the same one as it happens for normal prototype properties or every instance's `a` is different `myObject()` instance?

See this http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html: every TodoList instance will share the same localStorage, so the same Backbone.LocalStorage() instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this will help you out:

```
var Person = function (name, age) {
    this.getName = function () { return name; };
    this.getAge  = function () { return age; };
};


var Employee = function (employee_id) {
    this.printBadge = function () {
        console.log("#" + employee_id + " | " + this.record.getName());
    };
};

Employee.prototype.record = new Person("Bob", 32);

var jim  = new Employee(1),
    doug = new Employee(2);

jim.printBadge(); //  #1 | Bob
doug.printBadge(); // #2 | Bob
```

The "prefer composition to inheritance" mantra goes quadruple for JavaScript.
You can quite happily override a particular *object* on a person:

```
jim.record = { getName : function () { return "Jim"; } };
jim.printBadge();  // #1 | Jim
doug.printBadge(); // #2 | Bob
```

Just be careful when modifying properties of the prototype object (the object which instances refer to).

```
var jeff = new Employee(3);
jeff.record.getName = function () { return "OMG! Yuse guys is scr00d!" };

jim.printBadge();  // #1 | Jim
doug.printBadge(); // #2 | OMG! Yuse guys is scr00d!
jeff.printBadge(); // #3 | OMG! Yuse guys is scr00d!
```

Reason being that you changed a property of the shared, prototype object (static, in other languages), rather than replacing the WHOLE prototype object (referencing a new object, instead of the static object) like in Jim's case.

But the `X.prototype.y = new Z();` can be seen like this, simply:

```
var bob = new Person("Bob", 32);
Employee.prototype.record = bob;

var jim  = new Employee(1),
    doug = new Employee(2),
    jeff = new Employee(3);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, all your instances of `myObject` will have the same `__proto__`.

If you access `a` from an object, you'll access the one of the prototype but if you set `a` on one object, then this object will have whatever `a` you gave him while the others will keep the old one.

Comment: see this http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html, every TodoList will share the same localStorage so the same Backbone.LocalStorage(), right?

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-189
From what I was able to understand, it seems like yes. But since they have inheritance methods etc., I'm not sure. It could be that the Collection constructor clones the localStorage property or something like that. But I didn't see anything.

Comment: no no, it doesn't clone anything. I tought that since it used the new keyword a new object would be created for each instance

Comment: Well no since it's a property of the prototype. And you don't set it, you just use its methods.